# Invalid authorization specification

Tags: c#, string, ms-access, oledbconnection, configurationmanager

please help me to solve the problem.

i am getting the following problem

```
OleDbException was unhandled by user code
Invalid authorization specification
```

my code:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLEDbConnection"].ToString();
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["App_Data\\DavidsFlowershop.mdb"].ToString());
    string a = "select ProductName, Price from Products_tbl where ID=" + Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
try
    {
        con.Open(); <-- i got my problem here
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(a, con);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
```

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OLEDbConnection" connectionString="data source=App_Data\DavidsFloweShop.mdb; Provider=SQLOLEDB" providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection"/>
```

Comment: Add a `User Id=XYZ` property. I got the same error after reusing a connection string that wasn't intended for ole db. Changing the `User=XYZ` to `User Id=XYZ` fixed it. You may also decide to use windows authentication, in which case you can add `Integrated Security=SSPI` and remove the `User Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

The connection string in your web.config is

```
data source=App_Data\DavidsFloweShop.mdb; Provider=SQLOLEDB
```

but

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB
```

won't work. If your code will be running as 32-bit you'll need to use

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0
```

If that doesn't work then your code may be running as 64-bit, in which case you'll need to use

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

and ensure that you have the 64-bit version of the [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255) installed.

Comment: i tried to change the Provider=SQLOLEDB to Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 but i got this error . 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\App_Data\DavidsFloweShop.mdb' is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: i change the data source now i am getting this problem. "No value given for one or more required parameters." from this code -  OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); @Gord Thompson

Comment: @J.Anne That would be a different problem. After you have searched Stack Overflow (and the Web at large) if you still need assistance with the new error message then you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your connection string.

Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com and see whether there is an example which applies to your specific case/DB technology.